# Filtering unique values from array of arrays

Tags: php

Is there a way to improve this php code?

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$unique_emails = [];

$big_array_full_of_emails = [
    array('skywalker1@dagobah.jedi', 'chewbacca1@wookies.win'),
    array('skywalker1@dagobah.jedi', 'chewbacca1@wookies.win'),
    array('skywalker2@dagobah.jedi', 'chewbacca2@wookies.win'),
    array('skywalker3@dagobah.jedi', 'chewbacca3@wookies.win'),
    array('skywalker4@dagobah.jedi', 'chewbacca4@wookies.win'),
    array('skywalker5@dagobah.jedi', 'chewbacca5@wookies.win'),
];

foreach ($big_array_full_of_emails as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $email) {
        if (!in_array($email, $unique_emails)) {
            $unique_emails[] = $email;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($unique_emails);
```

@little_coder - Kris Roofe has posted an idea of what I'm looking for. Just looking for possibly more efficient or clearer ways to perform the logic.

Comment: Please don't fill your question with junk text to get around the code/text balance requirement. Instead, find something useful to say about the problem.

Comment: Please add more details on what you would like to achieve on your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with,[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2040af06b91467e00a5189f4002c7e731df1b978)

```
$result = array_unique(array_reduce($big_array_full_of_emails,"array_merge",[]));
```

You also can do it in a more efficient way,

```
$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($big_array_full_of_emails,function($v)use(&$result){$result[$v] = $v;});
```

---

If you want to use a sequence index, just add `$result = array_values($result);`